# Handle transaction across Micro-services in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, axios, sequelize.js

I have two services that both of them create a record in a database
test2 creates a People
test create a user that needs people's Id to store in the user

in this example, I want to delete (rollback) created people if I encounter any error in creating the user.

```
 async test(req, res) {
        let t = await sequlize.transaction();
        try {
            let rs = await this.getEurekaManager('education');
            const instance = this.createAxiosInstance(req.payload);
            let response = await instance.post(rs.homePageUrl + '/api/v1/TermLessons/test2', {
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Doe"
            }, {headers: {'Transaction-Id': t.id}});
            let person = response.data;
            await model.Users.create({
                Username: "johnDoe",
                PersonId: person.PersonId
            }, {transaction: t});
            await t.commit();
            res.json("Successfully");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            await t.rollback();
            res.json(error);
        }
    }

    async test2(req, res) {
        let t = await sequlize.transaction({id: req.headers['transaction-id']}); // Get the transaction ID from the headers
        try {
            let person = await model.People.create({
                FirstName: req.body.firstName,
                LastName: req.body.lastName
            }, {
                returning: true,
                transaction: t
            });
            // associate the created Person with the transaction
            await t.commit();
            res.json(person);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            await t.rollback();
            res.json(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.